# Mongoose, apply `.aggregate()` on array of subdocuments and get the result with other fields of document in least number of queries

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

This is my Mongoose Model:

```
const postSchema = new Schema({
    user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true
    },

    caption: {
        type: String
    },

    action: {
        type: [{
            actionName: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            user: {
                type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'User'
            }
        }],
        default: []
    },

    shares: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }];
});
```

All I want is to have a mongodb query with or without using `.aggregate()` to get the `user` & `caption` field as it is but instead of `action` and `shares` I want their counts for a particular document.

**Sample Document**

```
{
    _id: "fgsergehegoieofgesfglesfg",

    user: "dfjksjdnfkjsdfkjsdklfjglkbj",

    caption: "This is the post caption",

    action: [
        {
            actionName: 'e1', user: "sdfasdsdfasdfdsdfac951e5c"
        },
        {
            actionName: 'e1', user: "asdfmadfadfee103c9c951e5d"
        },
        {
            actionName: 'e2', user: "op34937cdbae0cd4160bbec"
        },
        {
            actionName: 'e2', user: "2543ebbasdfd1750690b5b01c"
        },
        {
            actionName: 'e3', user: "asdfcfebdb5dd1750690b5b01d"
        },
    ],

    shares: ["ewrebdb5ddadsf5069sadf1d", "asdfsdfbb85dd1750690b5b01c", "fasec92dsfasde103c9c95df5d"]
};
```

Desired output after query:

```
{
    _id: "fgsergehegoieofgesfglesfg",
    user: 'dfjksjdnfkjsdfkjsdklfjglkbj',
    caption: 'This is the post caption',
    actionCount: [{ count: 1, actionName: 'e3' },
                 { count: 2, actionName: 'e2' },
                 { count: 2, actionName: 'e1' }],
    shareCount: 3
}
```

I am able do get following results using `.aggregate()`:

Query:

```
let data = await Test.aggregate([
            { $match: { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId("fgsergehegoieofgesfglesfg") } },
            { $unwind: "$action" },
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: "$action.actionName",
                    count: { $sum: 1 }
                }
            },
            {
                $project: {
                    _id: 0,
                    actionName: "$_id",
                    count: 1
                }
            }
        ]);
```

Result:

```
[
  { count: 1, actionName: 'e3' },
  { count: 2, actionName: 'e2' },
  { count: 2, actionName: 'e1' } 
]
```

I just want to put this in the original document and get the result. Also, doing the same for `share` field. It would be better if this can be done in single query. I have tried using `$replaceRoot` along with `$mergeObjects` but don't know how to correctly use them. I am very new to mongodb and mongoose.

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're aggregating a nested array you need to run `$group`twice and `$first` can be used to preserve original document's field values:

```
await Test.aggregate([
    { $match: { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId("fgsergehegoieofgesfglesfg") } },
    { $unwind: "$action" },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: { _id: "$_id", actionName: "$action.actionName" },
            user: { $first: "$user" },
            caption: { $first: "$caption" },
            count: { $sum: 1 },
            shareCount: { $first: { $size: "$shares" } }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id._id",
            user: { $first: "$user" },
            caption: { $first: "$caption" },
            shareCount: { $first: "$shareCount" },
            actionCount: {
                $push: {
                    actionName: "$_id.actionName",
                    count: "$count"
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7Mhdz6xpcLd)

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I need. But I hope using multiple `$group` for cases with 1000s of actions doesn't increase latency of query too much. Can you suggest best way to learn mongodb?

Comment: @NeetigyaChahar documentation is definitely the best way to study MongoDB